# Send message in spanish from Twilio using PHP

Tags: twilio

I Just wanted to know, Is Twilio spport multiple language to send sms?
If yes, then please let us know how we can implement it in our project.
I am are using PHP tech. to send sms.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hi Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio indeed supports multiple languages and unicode characters, so you should be perfectly able to send messages in Spanish with no trouble. You can read more about it [here](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/what-languages-are-supported-by-twilio-sms).

One thing to be aware of is the fact that unicode messages only support up to 70 characters each, so going over that will not only split the message, but count as two messages. you can also read about that [here](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/why-are-my-messages-with-unicode-being-split)

Hope this helps you